# comparing two identical objects return false in Unity 3D (c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a C# script on Unity 3D. I have two `Vector3` that are the same. When I do:

```
Debug.Log(vect1);
Debug.Log(vect2);
```

I get the same result `(500.0, 150.0, 0.0)`. The problem is that when I do `vect1.Equals(vect2)` I get false! How is it possible?

P.S.
I am sure that they are both `Vector3` because when I do `vect1.GetType()` and `vect2.GetType()` I always get `Vector3`.

Comment: Funny thing Vector.equals(Vector) returns true if value has the same X and Y values as this vector; otherwise, false. but Vector3.equals(Vector3) returns true if the current instance is equal to the specified object; otherwise, false.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms, welcome to the total dog's dinner that is C#'s `.Equals()` and `==` system. :(

Comment: Could be worse. At least we have MSDN !

Answer (score 5):

Despite being a `struct`, `Vector3` implements `Equals` via identity comparison. In other words, `vect1` will only equal `vect2` if they are the same instance.

However, `Vector3` does implement `==` to test for value equality, so use that instead.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms128863%28v=vs.90%29.aspx for details.

Comment: Where in the page you link to does it say that `Equals` is done by reference identity?

Comment: Vector3 that Unity uses is not the documentation that you referenced.  It uses its own Vector3 class (the one you give reference to is in the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.DirectX namespace) unity's vector 3 documentation is here http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Answer (score 1):

`Vector3` [overrides the `==` operator](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) to "return true for vectors that are really close to being equal".  Since you may have some imperceptible differences in your floating-point values you might try using `==` instead:

```
vect1 == vect2
```

Comment: I have just tried vect1==vect2 and I always get false

Answer (score 1):

Here is why you could see what happens

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(150.001f, 150.002f, 150.003f);
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(150.002f, 150.003f, 150.004f);
Debug.Log(v1);
Debug.Log(v2);
Debug.Log(v1 == v2);
Debug.Log(v1.Equals(v2));
Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(v1, v2) > 1e-3f);
```

This will print out

(150.0, 150.0, 150.0)

(150.0, 150.0, 150.0)

False

False

True

The issue is that your definition of close enough may be different from unity's. You can check that by using this function

```
public static bool AlmostEqual(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, float tolerance)
{
    return Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(v1, v2)) <= tolerance;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi guys I tell you how I solved the problem so far. I have made a member to member comparison.

```
int vect1x=(int)vect1.x;
int vect1y=(int)vect1.y;
int vect1z=(int)vect1.z;
int vect2x=(int)vect2.x;
int vect2y=(int)vect2.y;
int vect2z=(int)vect2.z;
Debug.Log((vect1x==vect2x)&&(vect1y==vect2y)&&(vect1z==vect2z));
```

I know that it's verbose but at least it works cause it's a simple comparison between integers...

Comment: You don't compare the two vectors but you compare their members.

Comment: Even worse, you compare the rounded down values!

Comment: yes but beacause in my game the block move discretly, by a fixed length